# How can I fix the segmentation fault in this assembler code?

Tags: assembly, x86, segmentation-fault, nasm

I'm doing a challenge and I got some shellcode. When I ran the shellcode using C, I got a segmentation error and I knew that it'd be no use trying to debug it from the pure hex so I converted it to assembler. This is my code.

```
jmp 0x40
pop eax
mov ecx, eax
mov ebx, 0x0
mov edx, 0x53
xor eax, eax
mov al,BYTE [ecx+ebx*1]
or cl,BYTE [edx]
push ebx
push ecx
push eax
mov ecx, esp
mov eax, 0x4
mov ebx, 0x1
push edx
mov edx, 0xa000001
or al,BYTE [eax]
int 0x80
pop edx
pop ecx
pop ecx
pop ebx
inc ebx
inc ebx
dec edx
jne 0x13
mov eax,0x1
mov ebx,0xa0a0000
add BYTE [eax],al
int 0x80
call 0x8
```

I'm really not great at assembler so can anyone give me some tips to figure out why the segmentation error is happening? I've tried to research but most answers are people talking about compilation and not the actual code itself.

Comment: You might tell us what instruction faults..

Comment: The code you provided is incomplete. For example, you `pop eax` and move this mystery value into ecx. You then proceed to use this mystery value in the indirect addressing here: `mov al,BYTE [ecx+ebx*1]`. There could be a segfault here or it could be somewhere else. We need more information from you as this code is incomplete. Because you are having a segfault, this means this relates to your memory accessing. I would look at the indirect addressing you are doing as point of failure for you, but again, this is a shot in the dark. We don't have enough information right now.

Comment: Please comment your code so we get a broader understanding of what you're trying to accomplish

Comment: The targets of all the jumps and calls is unknown since you don't provide any address information for where your instructions are located.

Comment: @CodeDoggo that's not a mystery value. It's a well known shellcode trick to write position independent code. Note that the first instruction is a `jmp 0x40` where you have a `call 0x8` which presumably goes back to `pop eax` (the 0x8 is probably disassembly error). Hence that puts the address of the end of the shellcode into `eax`. There is however missing data after the code shown. That seems to be some sort of bytecode encoding a sequence of syscalls that this shellcode then executes in a loop.